# Connect to json-rpc interface

Tags: java, c#, rpc, json-rpc, transmission

I'm trying to connect to the transmission rpc interface via C#/Java to get some informations back.
https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt
Unfortunatly I have problems to get the correct HTTP-Post to access the interface.
For example if I try this in C#:

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["torrent-get"] = "id";

        var response = client.UploadValues("http://ip:9091/transmission/rpc", values);

        var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        Console.WriteLine("" + responseString);
    }
```

Or if i use:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            String json = "{\"arguments\": {\"fields\": [ \"id\", \"name\", \"totalSize\" ],\"ids\": [ 7, 10 ]},\"method\": \"torrent-get\",\"tag\": 39693}";
            var response = webClient.UploadString("http://192.168.240.171:9091/transmission/rpc", "POST", json);
            Console.WriteLine(""+response);
        }
```

I get the following error:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The Remoteserver returned an exception: (409) conflict.*

Answer (score 1):

You must save the **X-Transmission-Session-Id** provided in the 409 response and resubmit the request with a **X-Transmission-Session-Id** property added to your request header.

Example in java :

```
int index = responseString.indexOf("X-Transmission-Session-Id:");
String sessionId = responseString.substring(index + 27, index + 75);
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Transmission-Session-Id", sessionId);
```